# How to delete php session files from cantos tmp folder

Tags: shell, whm

I am using code-igniter php framework and it created 360k session files at /tmp folder now my server is down due to no more space.

session file name is look like : ci_sessionfffb1692761c84c4e5506919c8a4d966 (ci_sessionXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)

[image]

How to delete only those ci_session files using command for centOS?

Note I do not want to delete all files just file like ci_sessionfffb1692761c84c4e5506919c8a4d966 but those file does not have any extension (as you can see at attached image)

Comment: `unlink($file)` - is the typical way to delete a file (assuming PHP has privilege to do so)  I don't know the merits or de-merits you'll get for deleting session files, but whatever .... lol  ... It's  just a file, right, what could go wrong.

Comment: I want to delete using Linux command in tmp folder (its located in server root folder ) , you can not delete using PHP

Comment: than PHP cannot delete -via- command line either.  I forget but there is a way to have the terminal ask you before deleting each file in a folder.  I had to do that once for a file that had stinking quotes in it.

Comment: Something like `rm -i ci_session*`  or you can use the folder  `-i = Confirm each file before delete:`

Comment: ci_sessionfffb1692761c84c4e5506919c8a4d966  this file does not have any extension and i don't want to delete all files from folder because it OS Root/tmp folder.

Comment: with `-i` it will say `> delete file BlahBlah y,n` or something like that for each file.  Then you just say `y` or `n` if you want it.

Comment: :( i can not test on LIVE server, that's why i need confirmed command

Comment: solution :  find . -name "ci_session*" -exec rm {} \;

Comment: `i can not test on LIVE server` - sort of a moot point.  Unless you trust random People on SO.  Always research command line solutions before using, that should go without saying.  So rather or not you can test it on the live server doesn't really matter because at some point you will be testing it when you use it on the live server.  In any case, what I gave you was about the safest (albeit slowest) method because it requires user (you) to confirm each deletion.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
Go to folder : like cd /tmp
run :  find . -name "ci_session*" -exec rm {} \;
```